# How can I regenerate the System V symbolic links?

Tags: boot, services

I accidentally deleted all of the symlinks in `/etc/rc1.d/`. How can I regenerate them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<del>The most reliable way to get the symlinks back would be reinstalling the packages which have an initscript in it.</del>

I've noticed that neither `dpkg-reconfigure` nor `apt-get --reinstall install` restores the symlinks. Not all scripts comply with the LSB standards and do not provide a `# Default-(Start|Stop)` line.

The below (tested) script looks in the post-installation script of packages for the `update-rc.d` command which adds the startup script. Previous links had to be deleted in order to work, hence the `update-rc.d -f [script-name] remove` line. I've verified that all links are properly put back, the only missing file was a `README` file, but that's not critical.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /etc/init.d && for file in *; do
    if [ -x "$file" ]; then
        pkg=$(dpkg-query -S "/etc/init.d/$file" | cut -d: -f1)
        if [ -z "$pkg" ]; then
            echo "**WARNING** No related package found, skipping file: $file"
        else
            postinst="/var/lib/dpkg/info/$pkg.postinst"
            if [ -r "$postinst" ]; then
                update=$(grep -Po "(?<!#)\s*update-rc\.d\s+$file\s+((start|stop|defaults)[\s\dS\.]+)+" "$postinst" | sed -e 's/^\s*//' -e 's/\s\+/ /g')
                if [ -n "$update" ]; then
                    sudo update-rc.d -f "$file" remove
                    sudo $update
                else
                    if [ -e "/etc/init/$file.conf" ]; then
                        echo "$file has been moved to Upstart"
                    else
                        echo "No update-rc.d line found for $file"
                    fi
                fi
            else
                echo "No post-installation script found for $pkg"
            fi
        fi
    else
        echo "Not an executable, ignoring file: $file"
    fi
done
```

If you want to repair it manually, you can use the following:

- `dpkg-query -S /etc/init.d/[script-name]` - retrieves the package name responsible for the file
- `less /var/lib/dpkg/info/[package-name].postinst` - search for "update-rc.d" to get the command needed to install the startup scripts

Resources:

- [Manual page of `update-rc.d`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/en/man8/update-rc.d.8.html)

Comment: You're a lifesaver. [My results](http://paste.ubuntu.com/626763/), for interested readers.